# FirebaseFirestoreSwift Conversion To Swift 5

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I am working with Firebase and Firestore in an iOS app. I am using the FirebaseFirestoreSwift pod but receive the following warning when it is used.

> Conversion to Swift 5 is available.

I understand that the Firebase team has not updated this pod to Swift 5. How do we get rid of this warning, use Swift 5 for the project, and still work with FirebaseFirestoreSwift to get all of the added benefits?